# Synchronization of two timers (setInterval)

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm working in an script which contains a function that needs to be called at every 10 minutes. Also, to inform the user of how many time is left before reloading of the function (via AJAX, but this is not relevant now), I put a little regressive timer.

This is the main structure:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Test's function
    function loadDate() {
        var myDate = new Date();
        $("#dateload").html(myDate);
    };

    // Startup Variables
    countermin = 10; // 10 minutes
    countersec = 60;
    minpass = 0;
    secpass = 0

    // Showing info before timer.
    $("#reloadtime").html("Function will be reloaded in " + countermin + "m<b>" + (60 - countersec) + "</b>s<br/>(countersec's value: " + countersec + " - secpass' value: " + secpass + ")");
    $("#timescalled").text("The date function has been called " + minpass + " times  after page's load.");

    loadDate();


    // FIRST setInterval
    // It's our timer.
    intvl1 = setInterval(function () {
        if (countersec++ == 60) {
            countermin--;
            countersec = 1;
        }

        if (countermin < 0) {
            countermin = 9;
            countersec = 1;
            secpass = 0;
        }

        secpass++;

        $("#reloadtime").html("Function will be reloaded in " + countermin + "m<b>" + (60 - countersec) + "</b>s<br/>(countersec's value: " + countersec + " - secpass' value: " + secpass + ")");

    }, 1000);

    // SECOND setInterval
    // Counting 10 minutes to execute the function again (and again...).        
    intvl2 = setInterval(function () {

        minpass++;
        $("#minpass").text("The date function has been called " + minpass + " times after page's load.");
        loadDate();

    }, 600000);

});
```

My problem is: both timers are not synchronized. The `intvl2` is executing the function and going back before the timer (`intvl1`) reaches 0. The error is about 20 seconds, increasing after each 10 minutes.

If you compare with the time printed on beginning, around 6, 7 minutes of execution you can see difference with in the times, when comparing with your PC's clock.

How can I get them synchronized?

You can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxrX8/).

Comment: should 'countersec = 1;' not be countersec = 0? You're adding 1 to it, testing if it == 60 then setting to 1 if so - surely 0? Would lose you a second per minute of the main timer

Comment: ..personally I'd set a countdown from 600 and just decrement that every second. You can turn that into a mins and secs display easily - saves a lot of code..

Comment: Windsor, I thought in this, however, if I lose 1 second per minute, I would have a deficit of 10 seconds after 10 minutes, not 20 seconds as it is.

However, when looking on the fiddle, you can see that 10 minutes turns on 600 seconds (perceived on `secpass`). So, using the other concept you are saying (which is very clever!) would incur in the same thing also... =\

Comment: using two independent timers is doomed to failure.

Comment: for the record, I'd go with the single timer approach too. I wanted to make minimal edits to your code but it's an over-complicated way of doing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler approach would be to use a single timer that does both things, updates the countdown information and triggers the event. Below is an example:

```
var oneSecond = 1000;
var counter = 0;

var eventInterval = 5 * oneSecond;
var timesTriggered = 0;

setInterval(function () {

    counter = (counter + oneSecond) % eventInterval;
    $('.countdown').text((eventInterval - counter) / oneSecond);

    if(counter == 0){
        timesTriggered++;
        $('.timesTriggered').text(timesTriggered);
    }

}, oneSecond);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TFDSU/3/

Answer (score 0):

I've hacked about with your code a bit - I can't sit through a 10 minute countdown :) so I switched it to a minute and some other changes but this is working fine and not losing time..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Function of Test
function loadDate() {
    var myDate = new Date();
    $("#dateload").html(myDate);
};

countersec = 60; //
minpass = 0;

$("#reloadtime").html("Function will be reloaded in "+countersec+"</b>s<br/>");
$("#timescalled").text("The date function has been called " + minpass + " times after page's load.");
loadDate();

intvl1 = setInterval(function () {
    countersec--;
    if (!countersec) { countersec=60; }
    $("#reloadtime").html("Function will be reloaded in "+countersec+"</b>");
}, 1000);

intvl2 = setInterval(function () {

    minpass++;
    $("#minpass").text("The date function has been called " + minpass + " times after page's load.");
    loadDate();

}, 60000);

});
```